# How to add a header and footer to every page without overlapping the main content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, puppeteer

This is how I'm trying to generate the pdf

```
// Create a browser instance
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

// Create a new page
const page = await browser.newPage();

// Set the page content
const rawHtml = fs.readFileSync('public/pdf-templates/quotation.html', 'utf-8');
const template = hbs.compile(rawHtml)(data);

// Read the header and footer HTML files
const headerTemplate = fs.readFileSync('public/pdf-templates/header/header.html', 'utf-8');
const footerTemplate = fs.readFileSync('public/pdf-templates/footer/footer.html', 'utf-8');

// Pass the required data to the header and footer templates
const headerWithData = hbs.compile(headerTemplate.toString())(data);
const footerWithData = hbs.compile(footerTemplate.toString())(data);

// Combine the header, main content, and footer into a single HTML template
const mainContentWithHeaderFooter = `
  <html>
    <head>
      <style>
        @page {
          size: A4;
          @top-center {
            content: element(header);
          }
          @bottom-center {
            content: element(footer);
          }
        }
        html, body {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
        }
        #main-content {
          flex: 1;
          padding-top: 40mm; /* Add the height of the header */
          padding-bottom: 40mm; /* Add the height of the footer */
        }
        #header {
          font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
          color: #111111;
          font-size: 16px;
          text-align: left;
          position: fixed;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          right: 0;
          height: 40mm; /* Adjust the height of the header */
        }
        #footer {
          font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
          color: #111111;
          font-size: 16px;
          text-align: left;
          position: fixed;
          bottom: 0;
          left: 0;
          right: 0;
          height: 40mm; /* Adjust the height of the footer */
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="header">${headerWithData}</div>
      <div id="main-content">${template}</div>
      <div id="footer">${footerWithData}</div>
    </body>
  </html>
`;

// Set the page content
await page.setContent(mainContentWithHeaderFooter, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });

// Wait for any pending image requests to complete
await page.waitForFunction(() => {
  const images = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('img'));
  return images.every(img => img.complete);
});

// To reflect CSS used for screens instead of print
await page.emulateMediaType('screen');

// Download the PDF
const pdf = await page.pdf({
  displayHeaderFooter: true,
  headerTemplate: '', // Empty because the header is already part of the main content
  footerTemplate: '', // Empty because the footer is already part of the main content
  path: `public/pdf/${quotationId}.pdf`,
  margin: { top: '0', right: '0px', bottom: '0', left: '0px' },
  printBackground: true,
  format: 'A4',
});

// Close the browser instance
await browser.close();
```

I had to do it like this because otherwise the styles and the images of the header and footer wouldn't be loaded. But how do I not overlap the main content with the header and footer of every page after the first header.

When I did it like this.

```
// Set the page content
await page.setContent(template, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });

// Wait for any pending image requests to complete
await page.waitForFunction(() => {
  const images = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('img'));
  return images.every(img => img.complete);
});

// To reflect CSS used for screens instead of print
await page.emulateMediaType('screen');

// Download the PDF
const pdf = await page.pdf({
  displayHeaderFooter: true,
  headerTemplate: headerWithData, // Empty because the header is already part of the main content
  footerTemplate: footerWithData, // Empty because the footer is already part of the main content
  path: `public/pdf/${quotationId}.pdf`,
  margin: { top: '0', right: '0px', bottom: '0', left: '0px' },
  printBackground: true,
  format: 'A4',
});
```

the main content wouldn't overlap but the header and footer wouldn't be loaded with all of their images.